# Unlimited Custom Form Fields - Without Ajax

Tags: 8, forms

I have a simple form where users can set the number of fields they need. Users may need 100+ fields so I am not using ajax "add more" options.

With the below code, everything works (Even though you have to save the form twice, once to add the fields, twice to save the data), but I get an Undefined offset notice `Notice: Undefined offset: n` anytime I increase the field count and save the form.

As I'm not sure a better way to ask this question...

1) I know the code below is not perfect UX (having to save a form twice), does Drupal offer any API advantages to my approach I am not aware of?

2) Is there a way to handle/suppress these notices?

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  $config = $this->config('MYMODULE.settings');

  $form['#tree'] = TRUE;

  $form['fieldset'] = [
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
  ];

  $form['fieldset']['field_number'] = [
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#default_value' => $config->get('field_number') ?: 1,
  ];

  for ($i = 0; $i < $config->get('field_number'); $i++) {

    $form['fieldset']['field'][$i] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#default_value' => $config->get('field')[$i] ?: '',
    ];

  }

  return parent::buildForm($form, $form_state);
}

public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $values = $form_state->getValues();

  $this->configFactory->getEditable('MYMODULE.settings')
    ->set('field_number', $values['fieldset']['field_number'])
    ->set('field', $values['fieldset']['field'])
    ->save();

  parent::submitForm($form, $form_state);

}
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the error? Also note that if you add form elements without Drupal #ajax, you will get an error. When using the form API, you MUST use #ajax to add/remove form fields. There is no other option.

Comment: The error comes from `'#default_value' => $config->get('field')[$i]`. So if you have 1 field and add 100, you get 100 notices of undefined offset. Not sure how to get an un-submitted form field value into $form_state as form fields don't have any type of `'#onblur'`or anything as far as I know. Hoping to add 100+/- fields in one click.

Comment: To avoid the error use `isset()`. For dynamic forms in general, try to not submit and save the values until the end. Rebuild the form instead, then check in `buildForm()` the value of `field_number` in `$form_state` and build the dynamic form elements accordingly.

Comment: See [Examples](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples), when you set `$nojs` in the ajax examples you get dynamic forms rebuilding without `#ajax`: https://cgit.drupalcode.org/examples/tree/ajax_example/src/Form

Comment: Maybe I need to ask another question. If I implement `$form_state->setRebuild(TRUE)` via a submit form element, I am not sure how to get the altered/active `field` value, not the `[#default_value]`.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was from improper checking of array key values. Below is the approach for non-ajax form adjustment (which is very similar to ajax).

**MYMODULE/src/Form.php**:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  // get form config.
  $config = $this->config('MYMODULE.settings');

  // Set our count. Used in for loop below.
  if (!empty($form_state->getValue(['fieldset', 'field_count']))) {
    // get $form_state count value.
    $defaultCount = $form_state->getValue(['fieldset', 'field_count']);
  }
  else {
    // Get config count value.
    $defaultCount = $config->get('field_count');
  }

  $form['#tree'] = TRUE;

  // Fieldset item.
  $form['fieldset'] = [
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#prefix' => '<div id="fieldset-wrapper">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  ];

  // Field count item.
  $form['fieldset']['field_count'] = [
    '#type' => 'number',
    '#title' => 'Number',
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#default_value' => $config->get('field_count') ?: 1,
  ];

  // Rebuild submit item.
  $form['fieldset']['rebuild'] = [
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Apply number',
    // Make our call to the rebuild function.
    '#submit' => ['::rebuildFormSubmit'],
  ];

  // Loop through our count and create form items.
  for ($i = 0; $i < $defaultCount; $i++) {

    $form['fieldset']['field'][$i] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      // This is important. Must check isset() to avoid Undefined index notices.
      '#default_value' => isset($config->get('field')[$i]) ? $config->get('field')[$i] : '',
    ];

  }

  return parent::buildForm($form, $form_state);

}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function rebuildFormSubmit(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form_state->setRebuild(TRUE);
}
```

Related question: [Get an Un-submitted/Active Form Field Value in $form_state?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/277980/get-an-un-submitted-active-form-field-value-in-form-state/277990#277990).