# Get an Un-submitted/Active Form Field Value in $form_state?

Tags: 8, forms

I am unsure how to get unsubmitted/active form field values from a number/textfield into $form_state. `field_count` could be saved as `4`, then is changed to `115`, how do I pass that change to $form_state before a submit during `$form_state->setRebuild(TRUE);`?

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  $config = $this->config('MYMODULE.settings');

  $form['#tree'] = TRUE;

  $form['fieldset'] = [
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
  ];

  $form['fieldset']['field_count'] = [
    '#type' => 'number',
    '#default_value' => $config->get('field_count') ?: 1,
  ];

  // This doesnt get a usable value.
  $form_state->set('field_count_state', $form['fieldset']['field_count']);

  $form['fieldset']['rebuild'] = [
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Rebuild',
    '#submit' => ['::rebuildFormSubmit'],
  ];

  $form['fieldset'] = [
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
  ];

  for ($i = 0; $i < $config->get('field_count'); $i++) {

    $form['fieldset']['field'][$i] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#default_value' => $config->get('field')[$i] ?: '',
    ];

  }

  return parent::buildForm($form, $form_state);

}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function rebuildFormSubmit(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form_state->setRebuild(TRUE);
  // ???.
  $this->messenger()->addMessage($form_state->get('field_count_state'));
}
```

Comment: With the #tree option you should find the field value in `$form_state->getValue(['fieldset', 'field_count']);`

Answer (score 1):

**MYMODULE/src/Form.php**:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  // get form config.
  $config = $this->config('MYMODULE.settings');

  // Set our count. Used in for loop below.
  if (!empty($form_state->getValue(['fieldset', 'field_count']))) {
    // get $form_state count value.
    $defaultCount = $form_state->getValue(['fieldset', 'field_count']);
  }
  else {
    // Get config count value.
    $defaultCount = $config->get('field_count');
  }

  $form['#tree'] = TRUE;

  // Fieldset item.
  $form['fieldset'] = [
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#prefix' => '<div id="fieldset-wrapper">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  ];

  // Field count item.
  $form['fieldset']['field_count'] = [
    '#type' => 'number',
    '#title' => 'Number',
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#default_value' => $config->get('field_count') ?: 1,
  ];

  // Rebuild submit item.
  $form['fieldset']['rebuild'] = [
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Apply number',
    '#submit' => ['::rebuildFormSubmit'],
    '#ajax' => [
      'callback' => '::fieldCallback',
      'wrapper' => 'fieldset-wrapper',
    ],
  ];

  // Loop through our count and create form items.
  for ($i = 0; $i < $defaultCount; $i++) {

    $form['fieldset']['field'][$i] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#default_value' => isset($config->get('script')[$i]) ? $config->get('script')[$i] : '',
    ];

  }

  return parent::buildForm($form, $form_state);

}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function fieldCallback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  return $form['fieldset'];
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function rebuildFormSubmit(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form_state->setRebuild(TRUE);
}
```

This part in the `$form['fieldset']['rebuild']`:

```
'#ajax' => [
  'callback' => '::fieldCallback',
  'wrapper' => 'fieldset-wrapper',
],
```

along with:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function fieldCallback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  return $form['fieldset'];
}
```

Are the ajax options.

Comment: The last line by itself is not correct, try: `'#default_value' => isset($config->get('field')[$i]) ? $config->get('field')[$i] : '',`. Other than that, a form should work without #ajax as well, because this is the fallback for non-js clients.

Comment: Thank you, yes that modification resolves the `Undefined index` notices when not using ajax in the form. I have updated the answer.